# Hide onhover overlay on key press in Atom

Tags: overlay, atom-editor, onkeypress, onhover

In the [Atom](https://atom.io/) text editor, when I hover my mouse over a function signature, it shows an overlay:

[image: overlay]

The problem is that I use the keyboard to then try to type some code on the line below, and I can't see what I'm typing because the overlay is on top of it.  This occurs frequently.

How can I make the overlay disappear onkeypress?  If that's impossible, then how can I disable it entirely?

Comment: What package are you using that provides that overlay? It's not builtin to Atom.

Comment: @wjandrea It seems that the overlay existence and content comes from [ide-python](https://atom.io/packages/ide-python).  There is a separate package called atom-ide-datatip that makes it look pretty.

Comment: It looks like there is a setting `Jedi Hover` > `Enabled` that I can uncheck to remove the overlay.  I don't know how I could go about making it disappear on keypress.

Comment: Maybe you could switch to [autocomplete-python](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-python)? That's what I use, and it goes away on keypress.